# How do I properly declare global variable?

Tags: perl, variables, declaration

ALL,

Consider this piece of code:

```
our $classwork = 0;
while( <INFILE> )
{
    chomp;
    next if $. == 1;
    if( $year >= 1992 && $year <= 1995 )
    {
        $classwork = (split( /,/ ))[6];
        print "Classwork is: ", $classwork, "\n";
    }
    if( $year >= 1996 && $year <= 2001 )
    {
        $classwork = (split( /,/ ))[-1];
    }
    print "Classwork is: ", $classwork, "\n";
    if( $year == 2002 )
    {
        $classwork = (split( /,/ ))[-2];
    }
    if( $year == 2003 || $year == 2004 )
    {
        $classwork = (split( /,/ ))[23];
    }
    if( $year >= 2005 && $year <= 2009 )
    {
        $classwork = (split( /,/ ))[22];
    }
    if( $year >= 2010 && $year <= 2012 )
    {
        $classwork = (split( /,/ ))[20];
    }
    print "Classwork is: ", $classwork, "\n";
    $line = <STDIN>;
}
```

The last print statement does not want to print the variable. Even if I declare it as 'our' or just comment the declaration out.
What's more weird is that it happens only on the first iteration. The file has couple of thousand records and on the first iteration only the variable is undefined. All subsequent calls are good.

Any idea what is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: what is `$year` here? is this full text of yours script?

Comment: There is probably a line where there is not enough fields.

Comment: and i'm realy confused why you need to declare global variable here

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for us to replicate the problem for ourselves, but the most likely case is that the first line of the file does not contain properly-formatted data for whatever `$year` you're dealing with.  Perhaps the first line is a header?

Another possibility is that `$year` may not be set on the first pass through the `while` loop, so you never enter any of the `if` blocks which set `$classwork` and then it gets set at a later point in the loop.  Since you don't show where or how `$year` is set, we can't say whether this could be the issue or not.

To get the best possible answers, it's generally best to provide complete, runnable example code which demonstrates your issue with as little additional code as possible.  (In my experience, such examples are usually no more than 15-20 lines.)  Another benefit of doing this is that you will often discover the problem for yourself while in the process of finding the smallest possible program which demonstrates it.

Also, there is no evident reason why `$classwork` needs to be global.  Changing `our` to `my` in its current declaration should not affect any of the code you've shown and I would definitely consider moving `my $classwork` to be inside the `while` loop, unless there's some intended condition under which it shouldn't be reassigned on every pass and should instead retain its value from one iteration to the next.